# What is the best way to implement CSS reset

Tags: iphone, html, css, cross-browser, css-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best css reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

What is the best way to implement CSS reset?
My question is more in context of implementing layouts which would be cross-browser, cross-platform compliant.
E.g. layout should look similar on desktop browsers like ie, firefox and even on iPad and to some extent on iPhone as well.

Please let me know if I should apply CSS reset to acheive this.

Comment: Well this deceptively seems to be a duplicate question...However I do not just want to know about reset CSS...I want to know how well does it go with mobile browsers like iPhone, iPad, etc which I do not think has been answered...

Comment: I think you have not understood the question properly...I'll have to re-ask with a more specific title..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/):

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We researched the differences between default browser styles in order to precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.

I don't know how well it supports mobile, tablets, etc., however.

Comment: you beat me by 17 seconds.. lol.

Comment: Nice. Is it better than normal reset.css?

Comment: @Victor In my humble opinion, it probably won't make that much of a difference. Resets *might* work better with iPad/iPhone?

Comment: I haven't tried `normalize.css`. Will test it out when I am free. Learnt something new today. Thanks!

Comment: I would say the best thing about normalize.css is that it encourages developers to extend it into exactly what they want, treating it as a baseline rather than another stylesheet that clutters the works.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the best way to implement CSS reset?

Before answering your question, I think it's important to understand what a CSS reset **is** and **is not** going to do for you.

## What CSS Resets Do

The purpose of a CSS reset is to override the default styles that browsers use. That's about it.

There are a bunch of suggested styles that you'll probably find between most popular CSS resets that help to normalize some of the lesser-used elements. Additionally, there are a few necessary styles to make some browsers render HTML5 elements correctly.

## What CSS Resets Don't Do

Magic. Seriously, they're not a panacea. You'll still have to write a bunch more CSS to get a nice looking webpage. Just because *your* site uses a CSS reset *doesn't mean* that your site is better than another that doesn't. Many very attractive sites don't bother with a CSS reset, because they know they're going to override ***everything*** as part of the process anyway.

## When *should* you use a CSS reset?

You should use a CSS reset when you're not planning on styling elements much beyond their defaults. It's really helpful for normalizing margins, padding and font-size on block-level text elements such as `h#`, `p`, `blockquote`, `ul` and `ol`.

## When *shouldn't* you use a CSS reset?

You should *not* use a CSS reset when you're just blindly linking in someone elses CSS reset without any thought for what it's going to do to your layout. If you don't understand *exactly* what it's doing with your layout, you shouldn't be using it to begin with.

I usually don't recommend plain CSS resets to people because you often find style like `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` which are *not* helpful. At best you're going to force yourself to use higher specificity for other selectors down the road, and at worst, you're going to run into all sorts of style inheritance issues.

Instead of using a plain-jane reset, use a reset template, but fill in the styles for the elements you know. Instead of always having:

```
p
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

you should set it to what the default paragraph style will be (if you're working with a design from  someone else, style guides typically specify most of the styles that belong in a reset stylesheet):

```
p
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
}
```

## tl; dr.

Don't just blindly use a reset from someone else. Instead, pick out the useful styles that will actually be used, and specify useful defaults. There's no point to a CSS reset if you're only going to override everything in your default stylesheet anyway.

<sub>I typically call my "reset" stylesheets my `core.css` because it contains all of my core styles to the layout that i'm trying to produce</sub>

Comment: Thx a lot for that...But I wanted to know it's impact on mobile browsers like iPhone, iPad, etc

Comment: @testndtv, it's the same impact that it has on desktop browsers. There's no magic, it just overrides the default styles that they use.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to CSS frameworks, such as [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and [960.gs](http://960.gs/) and download their CSS packages, you will find the `reset.css` and other default css that we should use before designing a site. Just use those.

Answer (score 1):

[Meyerweb CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

This is what's recommended by most usually, it's what I use and I think it's the best out there.